# Data not storing in the DB [Laravel 5.5]

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.5. I wanted to store my data in the DB, but when i try to do it - nothing is happening. Here is my MarketController code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{


    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|unique:markets|max:255',
        'website' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
    ]);
    Market::create($request->all());
    return redirect('markets'); 
}
```

My save.blade.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <title>Create Market</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  @extends('layouts.app')
  @section('main')
  <form action="{{ route('markets.store') }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="DaBSErIRWPPI">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <label for="city">Location</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
    <label for="website">Market's website</label>
    <input type="text" name="website" id="website">
    <button type="submit"><a href="{{route('markets.store')}}">Add Market</a>
</button>
</form>
</form>
```

And here is index.blade.php code

```
<h1><a href="{{ route('markets.create', $market) }}">Add Market</a></h1>
```

Nothing happens. Please, help. Thank U!

Comment: any error? that showing after submit

Comment: @Rits, no, nothing

Comment: You must allow the required fields in Model as,      protected $fillable = ['column_name', 'column_name', 'column_name']

Comment: Since your directly adding the $request->all()  the laravel wont add unless and untill you do as above stated statment in your Model

Comment: @DanielKiz can you please post your model so that we can provide a more reliable solution

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari i have it in my code

Comment: Have you added {{ csrf_token() }} in form page. Did you check the type of HTTP request ie GET, POST, PUT, PATCH

Comment: Is the redirect happening successfully?

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari i have {{ csrf_field() }} method, how i see this store method not calling on this page

Comment: Can you paste your relevant route line in along with the database fields.

Comment: @DanielKiz before doing any stuff inside the controller action where your redirecting. Just **echo & exit**  and check in first line whether your getting the request to that action or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Route should show as my example as I don't know your Routes page title:

```
Route::post('store', 'MarketController@store')->name('store');
```

Realistically you should run: `php artisan make:request StoreRequest`

within StorageRequest.php change `authorize` from `return false;` to `return true;` and then add the rules:

```
return [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'website' => 'required',
    'city' => 'required'
]
```

Your controller can then be simplified:

```
public function store(StoreRequest $storeRequest)
{
    $form = $storeRequest->all();

    Market::create([
        'name' => $form['name'],
        'website' => $form['website'],
        'city' => $form['city']
    ]);

    return redirect('markets');

}
```

Your form is slightly over crammed here's a broken down version:

```
<form action="{{ route('store') }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

    <label for="city">Location</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city">

    <label for="website">Market's website</label>
    <input type="text" name="website" id="website">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**UPDATED**

Your example doesn't throw the error back to the form therefore here's another updated version:

```
<form action="{{ route('store') }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

    @if ($errors->has('name'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
    </span>
    @endif

    <label for="city">Location</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city">

    @if ($errors->has('city'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('city') }}</strong>
    </span>
    @endif

    <label for="website">Market's website</label>
    <input type="text" name="website" id="website">

    @if ($errors->has('website'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('website') }}</strong>
    </span>
    @endif

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So now, if the required field hasn't been filled it'll return throwing the error on the form stating which input field hasn't been filled in.